# Подскажите пожалуйсто $(window).scroll(function()

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

$('header') относиться к тегу html или css классу?

Answer (score 1):

Контекста я не вижу но в данном случае к тегу html.

Comment: Как сделать вложение. Например a внутри header или div header  типо <header>
<a href=""><img src="../images/ico2.png"></a>... ????

Comment: Сделать вложение чего и куда? С помощью **javascript**?

Comment: С помощью javascript. Если например нужно сделать так что бы тег a внутри тега div менял класс при прокрутке

Comment: Так а чем вас тот код который вы указали не устраивает?

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  //Если окно прокручено больше чем на 100 писелей
        $('some_div').addClass(".some_class");// Добовляем .some_class
    }
    else{
        $('some_div').removeClass(".some_class"); // Иначе убираем
    }
});`

Comment: Блин ну не то, как же вам обьяснить

Comment: Вот есть у меня шапка. Она изначально большая, мне нужно что бы при прокрутке она становилась маленькой. Некоторые кнопки прятались, а некоторые вообще положение меняли.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48298/discussion-between-tomasredl-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое! Сам нашёл решение, через document.getElementById